# is it possible in fabric.js to load json with different image source.?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to create a ID-card application using fabric.js. So the plan is to create the design of the id card. using default name, image, address. etc. and then apply that design to different employees.

So what I have achieved so far is 
1) the designing part 
2) saving the canvas in JSON 
3) reload the canvas form json

I will be fetching the employee information from the database and will display employee name in a drop-down. as i select the employee name from the drop-down i want the canvas to be replaced with employee information...

I got an example which loads the canvas from json and changes the property like height, width etc. is it possible to change the actual content itself like image source

```
canvas_.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(json_data), function(obj) {
  canvas_.renderAll();
  //console.log(' this is a callback. invoked when canvas is loaded!xxx ');
  canvas_.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    //console.log(obj.type);
    if (obj.type === 'image') {
      obj.set({
        left: 100,
        top: 200,
        height: 700,
        width: 700,
        scaleX: .35,
        scaleY: .35,
        lockScalingY: .35
      });
      canvas_.add(obj);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the reviver of [loadFromJSON()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) to get the object and then change source of image using [setSrc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#setSrc).

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(json_data), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
  if (object.type == 'image') {
    object.setSrc(url, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying.. i tried your code got error obj.setSrc is not a function

Comment: @Zakir Which version of fabricjs you are using?

Comment: version: "0.9.13"

Comment: i updated the fabricjs and its working thanks a lot you saved my day... and one more thing  the height and width of the image is changed... how to set all the properties like height, width and  angle of old image to replaced image

Comment: @Zakir check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077721/3551786), you need to use scaleX and scaleY for width and height.

Comment: perfect just what i need... you are awesome. one last thing.. if there are two images how to differentiate them for example one will be background image and other will be employee image...  
if (object.type == 'image') will consider both the images

Comment: @Zakir put custom property for employee image,and extend toObject of image like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511488/3551786) for image class.

Comment: thank you so much you gave the solutions to all my problems.... i have accepted your answer.. have a good day

Comment: aboute using scaleX and scaleY can you give a different example.... i dont understand this (  scaleX: canvas.width / img.width), why is canvas width divided by image width

Comment: @Zakir, create a demo and try to use that, you can understand. If still getting any problem ask in a new question with that demo.